# Returning a pointer to struct in a linked list class

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list

I am trying to write a linked list class with some basic features like add  node, delete a node and search recursively in the list. I have defined the head of the list as a private variable but I need to access it for the recursive search function so I tried to define a GetHead() function that will return the pointer to head. However I am having some trouble with compiling it in NetBeans.

Here is the class header

```
class List{
private:

    typedef struct node{
        int data;
        node* next;
    }*nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;

public: 
    List();
    void AddNode(int addData);
    void DelNode(int delData);
    void PrintList();
    void SearchRecursive(nodePtr Ptr, int searchVal);
    nodePtr GetHead();
};
```

The GetHead() function is as follows:

```
nodePtr List::GetHead(){
    return head;
}
```

When I compile, I get

```
error: unknown type name 'nodePtr'
error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int' 
       with an lvalue of  type 'nodePtr' (aka 'List::node *')
```

Is there a problem in how I am returning the pointer to the struct node?

Comment: `nodePtr GetHead();` This won't work for `public` access scope, since `nodePtr ` is declared in the `private` class section.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually, it works if you use `auto`. As long as you don't name the private thing...

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah, THX! Good to know, didn't think about `auto`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nodePtr` is defined in `List`, so you need the right scope:

```
List::nodePtr List::GetHead()
^^^^^^
```

Comment: Sure? The `nodePtr ` typedef is class `private`, while `GetHead()` is `public`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That doesn't stop you defining the function, it just makes it slightly inconvenient to use.

Comment: That seemed to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get it compiling:

1)You have defined a struct inside a class in private scope....That hides it from the rest of the world.
But as juanchopanza pointed out, you need to specify the scope.

2)Another way to do it would be to take the definition of node outside the class and it should work without changing the function prototype.

First one would be better because the rest of the world has no use for it apart from your linked list class.